# Capture and analyze audio on windows using C

Tags: c, windows, audio, audio-recording

I am building a program that requires recording audio and analyze it in real time or semi-real time (record short audio bits and analyze them one recording at the time).

I wrote the code for open and analyze WAV files (using libsndfile library).

Now I am having trouble in writing the code for recording from the PC mic and save it to a buffer/WAV file.
I tried using this sample - http://www.techmind.org/wave/. But I could not figure  out how to save the recorded buffer to WAV or how to use the recorded data itself.

The project's requirements are to write it in C and on windows.

I am looking for an efficient library for this purpose.

---

***Edit***: I managed to save the data as WAV the data after converting it from 16 bit to double using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
    int c = (waveIn[i + 1] << 8) | waveIn[i];
    double t = c / 32768.0;
    data[i] = t;
}
```

However, the recording is very noisey and unclear. Any suggestions?

---

Thanks

Comment: I am not the OP, but why this was downvoted? I am really interested in such question

Answer (score 1):

After a lot tinkering and testing, I gave up on using the windows API for this purpose and decided to go with [PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/).
They have several examples that tackle the problem.
I took one of PA examples and modified it so it fit my needs, and combined it with [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) based function for [saving WAV files](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/wavFiles.html).
This is a great low level solution.

In addition, if someone is looking for a high level solution for audio recording (with no control on sample rate and such), I recommend this [MCI based solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67568/Creating-a-Sound-Recorder-in-C-and-C).

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

[Previous question for saving a WAV file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438115/how-to-save-audio-data-in-memory-as-a-wav-file) There are a couple recommendations in the answers that you may want to pursue. Assuming your recording is actually occurring, you would want to place your code to save the recorded data inside the DO-WHILE loop right at the end.

Comment: I'll try saving the code inside the loop. I do have succesful experience with writing to WAV files with libsndfile.h. The problem is that I can't determine if I am "translating" the sampled data correctly or if the sampled data is even valid.

Comment: The noise concern would require a filtering solution. If you are plugging the mic into your PC, odds are creating a multi-pole notch active filter using op-amps is not the way to go. The author of the website at [link](http://www.iowahills.com/A7ExampleCodePage.html) did a pretty good job of explaining the concept.